# indesign color theme tool changing color of text

Tags: adobe-indesign

indesign *color theme tool* changes the color of any text in same text frame regardless of **different** paragraph styles.
It makes sense, but I was hoping I'd be able to pick a color from a visual for headline, another for subhead… no luck.

---

Anyone know of a workaround? thanks!

indesign color theme tool applies active color to ALL paragraphs styles in text:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji6TN.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have picked the colors, select the color (from theme) for your headline, now select the headline text, the color should get applied. Select the color again (from theme) for a subhead, select the subhead text, the color gets applied.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the reagular color picker while clicking on shift to get any color value from a visual.

Comment: Great approach! It seems it'd be quicker with the color theme tool, and does not require selecting the text prior to applying the color change. I find the selection distracting as it inverts colors… Can't quickly see what works best (the promise of the *color theme tool*)